# "No module named tkinter," but it works in terminal (VSCode for Ubuntu)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I just started learning how to create GUIs. I installed tkinter just as I was instructed, then wrote the following code:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def openWindow():
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    title = tk.Label(text="PyCalc")
    title.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

After calling this function to my main method, I immediately got this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`

I tried looking it up, but most responses weren't what I had hoped for. Mostly it was: "Have you tried installing tkinter?" (I have installed and even uninstalled a few times trying to get it right), or "does it work in the terminal?" (it does). I'm on Ubuntu if that helps, I installed tkinter by using `sudo apt install python3-tk`.

One solution led me to change my code as such:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def openWindow():
    root = Tk()
    
    title = Label(text="PyCalc")
    title.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

...and it still doesn´t work. Same error, nothing new.

The last solution is one that I wanted to try, but honestly I don't really get it. Someone on StackOverflow said it's an interpreter issue, and that the interpreter should be configured correctly. I don't know what the chosen interpreter should be, though, if not the recommended one. I tried the ctrl+shift+P keybind and I found myself at a menu of four different options for interpreters, or the option to set up a venv. I tried messing around with some of the options, but nothing seemed to work.

I've tried installing tkinter again, uninstalling it then reïnstalling it, using the `sudo apt install python-tk` instead of `python3-tk`, it works in the terminal, but not when called from VSCode. I've never had this problem before.

Comment: `tkinter` is part of Python default, the import name has changed from Python 2.x and 3.x, read the correct tutorial

Comment: This code can run correctly in python3.12. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Try this `sudo apt install python3.12-tk`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the value of `sys.path` in both an interpreter where tkinter works, and one where it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If the vscode was installed using `snap` or `flatpak`, this problem could arise. Instead install vscode in the following way. If you haven't uninstalled the already installed one, There will be two shortcut icons in the program list. Remember to launch(open) vscode with newly installed one.

1. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install package dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget -y
   ```
3. Add GPG key

   ```
   wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Add repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
   ```
5. Install vscode

   ```
   sudo apt install code
   ```

Kindly confirm in comment whether you got your issue rectified after doing this. I'm following this thread.